# Bottom Navigation com Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android

Olá, estou com problemas para configurar um Bottom Navigation em um layout Navigation Drawer. Se puderem dar alguma ideia, segue o código.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //BottomNavigationView menuBottom = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.menuBottom);
        //menuBottom.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);  


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }   


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_qrcode) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Leitor.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pesquisa) {


        }else if (id == R.id.nav_informacoes) {

        /*
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        */

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_compartilhar) {

            //PERMITE COMPARTILHAR O APP VIA EMAIL, WHATSAPP, ETC...
            Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("text/plain");
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Compartilhar o App");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "teste");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Compartilhar o App"));

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Preciso de algo como isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu estou usando **Navigation Component** na versão abaixo:

```
def nav_version = "2.0.0"
// Java language implementation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

Abaixo está minha implementação da `BottomNavigation View` junto com `Navigation Drawer`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "debinf MainActivity";

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavController navController;

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_bottomnav);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_sidebar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);

        setupNavigation();

    }

    private void setupNavigation() {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupNavigation: ");
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment);

        appBarConfiguration =
                new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
                        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
                        .build();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
        /*
        ** Listener for bottomNavigation must be called after been setupWithNavController
        ** This command will override NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)
        ** and the automatic transaction between fragments is lost
        * */
        //bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed: ");
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSupportNavigateUp: ");
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: SIDE BAR");

        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.main_menusidehome) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: conta");
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.main_menusideshop) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: compra");
        }
        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.main_menusidesearch) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: estatistica");
        }
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado. Boa sorte!